# Column standard deviation R

Tags: r, function

I was wondering if there was a built-in function in R that would compute the standard deviation for columns just like `colMeans` computes `mean` for every column. It would be simple enough to write my own mini function (a compound command that invokes things like `apply` with `sd`), but I was wondering if there was already something I could use whilst also keeping my code looking clean.

Comment: ...there, I would especially recommend sgibb's `colSdColMeans` as a fast implementation.

Comment: for a numeric matrix, easy enough (solutions below), but how about a solution for a dataframe that only works on numeric columns? Or uses a formula argument to select columns? `colmean(~x1+x2+x3,data=d)`?

Answer (score 71):

The general idea is to *sweep* the function across.  You have many options, one is `apply()`:

```
R> set.seed(42)
R> M <- matrix(rnorm(40),ncol=4)
R> apply(M, 2, sd)
[1] 0.835449 1.630584 1.156058 1.115269
R>
```

Comment: In apply(), the second argument, margin, "is a vector giving the subscripts which the function will be applied over."    
2 indicates columns

Answer (score 17):

Use `colSds` function from `matrixStats` library.

```
library(matrixStats)
set.seed(42)
M <- matrix(rnorm(40),ncol=4)
colSds(M)

[1] 0.8354488 1.6305844 1.1560580 1.1152688
```

Comment: Can you adjust this `colSds` for sums, not only for means?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for dataframes

Comment: convert data.frame to matrix

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use it with groups, you can use:

```
library(plyr)
mydata<-mtcars
ddply(mydata,.(carb),colwise(sd))



  carb      mpg       cyl      disp       hp      drat        wt     qsec        vs        am      gear
1    1 6.001349 0.9759001  75.90037 19.78215 0.5548702 0.6214499 0.590867 0.0000000 0.5345225 0.5345225
2    2 5.472152 2.0655911 122.50499 43.96413 0.6782568 0.8269761 1.967069 0.5270463 0.5163978 0.7888106
3    3 1.053565 0.0000000   0.00000  0.00000 0.0000000 0.1835756 0.305505 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
4    4 3.911081 1.0327956 132.06337 62.94972 0.4575102 1.0536001 1.394937 0.4216370 0.4830459 0.6992059
5    6       NA        NA        NA       NA        NA        NA       NA        NA        NA        NA
6    8       NA        NA        NA       NA        NA        NA       NA        NA        NA        NA
```

Comment: ...or without grouping: `colwise(sd)(mydata)`

Answer (score 2):

The package `fBasics` has a function `colStdevs`

```
 require('fBasics')
 set.seed(123)
 colStdevs(matrix(rnorm(1000, mean=10, sd=1), ncol=5))
[1] 0.9431599 0.9959210 0.9648052 1.0246366 1.0351268
```