# calculate the mean for each column of a matrix in R

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I am working on R in R studio.
I need to calculate the mean for each column of a data frame.

```
 cluster1  // 5 by 4 data frame
 mean(cluster1) //
```

I got :

```
  Warning message:
  In mean.default(cluster1) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

But I can use

```
  mean(cluster1[[1]])
```

to get the mean of the first column.

How to get means for all columns ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Useful self-help tools include the built-in [`apropos`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/apropos.html) (e.g. `apropos('mean')`), and [`findFn`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/sos/docs/findFn) in the `sos` package.

Comment: Also [this great reference card](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Baggott-refcard-v2.pdf).

Answer (score 90):

You can use `colMeans`:

```
### Sample data
set.seed(1)
m <- data.frame(matrix(sample(100, 20, replace = TRUE), ncol = 4))

### Your error
mean(m)
# [1] NA
# Warning message:
# In mean.default(m) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

### The result using `colMeans`
colMeans(m)
#   X1   X2   X3   X4 
# 47.0 64.4 44.8 67.8
```

Comment: What if we want to calculate the `median`, or `min`, `max`? Do we have something like `colMedians`?

Comment: @AnhTriet, maybe consider the ["matrixStats" package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/matrixStats/index.html)?

Comment: @TrietDoan If you have a dataframe and want to calculate medians, standard deviations, etc. use apply: `apply(df, 2, median)`. The '2' here means by column. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18047916/5824031

Answer (score 31):

You can use 'apply' to run a function or the rows or columns of a matrix or numerical data frame:

```
cluster1 <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=11:15, c=21:25, d=31:35)

apply(cluster1,2,mean)  # applies function 'mean' to 2nd dimension (columns)

apply(cluster1,1,mean)  # applies function to 1st dimension (rows)

sapply(cluster1, mean)  # also takes mean of columns, treating data frame like list of vectors
```

Comment: Better if you use `colMeans(m)` and `rowMeans(m)` instead. It is optimized and faster than `apply(cluster1,1,mean)`

Answer (score 12):

In case you have NA's:

```
sapply(data, mean, na.rm = T)      # Returns a vector (with names)   
lapply(data, mean, na.rm = T)      # Returns a list
```

Remember that "mean" needs numeric data. If you have mixed class data, then use:

```
numdata<-data[sapply(data, is.numeric)]  
sapply(numdata, mean, na.rm = T)  # Returns a vector
lapply(numdata, mean, na.rm = T)  # Returns a list
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use **purrr** package

```
# example data like what is said above
```

@A Handcart And Mohair

```
set.seed(1)
m <- data.frame(matrix(sample(100, 20, replace = TRUE), ncol = 4))


library(purrr)
means <- map_dbl(m, mean)

> means
#  X1   X2   X3   X4 
#47.0 64.4 44.8 67.8
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
mean(as.matrix(cluster1))
```

Answer (score 2):

try it ! also can calculate NA's data!

```
df <- data.frame(a1=1:10, a2=11:20)

df %>% summarise_each(funs( mean( .,na.rm = TRUE)))


# a1   a2
# 5.5 15.5
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class(mtcars)
my.mean <- unlist(lapply(mtcars, mean)); my.mean



   mpg        cyl       disp         hp       drat         wt       qsec         vs 
 20.090625   6.187500 230.721875 146.687500   3.596563   3.217250  17.848750   0.437500 
        am       gear       carb 
  0.406250   3.687500   2.812500
```

Answer (score 1):

colMeans(A, na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1)

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colSums.html

This is in the base class, so no library is required.

The first answer looks like it is using colMeans from the analytics library which is not available in the R version 4.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

Another option using the function `fmean` from the [collapse](https://sebkrantz.github.io/collapse/) package. Here is a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(1)
m <- data.frame(matrix(sample(100, 20, replace = TRUE), ncol = 4))
library(collapse)
fmean(m)
```

Output:

```
  X1   X2   X3   X4 
47.0 64.4 44.8 67.8
```

Answer (score 0):

**For diversity:** Another way is to converts a vector function to one that works with data
frames by using `plyr::colwise()`

```
set.seed(1)
m <- data.frame(matrix(sample(100, 20, replace = TRUE), ncol = 4))

plyr::colwise(mean)(m)


#   X1   X2   X3   X4
# 1 47 64.4 44.8 67.8
```