# Creating a matrix of means based on column time series in R

Tags: r, matrix, mean

I have 25 time series of monthly returns of different portfolios as columns (S1B1, S1B2, S1B3, S1B4, S1B5, S2B1, S2B2, S2B3, S2B4, S2B5, (...), S5B5):

```
S1B1 S1B2 S1B3 S1B4 S1B5 (...) S5B5   
0.2  0.1  2.1  3.2  1.2        0.3
0.3  1.2  2.6  2.1  6.3        0.2
0.5  0.5  0.5  2.2  6.2        1.2
0.4  1.2  2.2  1.1  0.5        2.1
```

I want to create a 5x5 matrix showing means for every column in the following way:

```
S1B1 S1B2 S1B3 S1B4 S1B5    
S2B1 S2B2 S2B3 S2B4 S2B5   
S3B1 S3B2 S3B3 S3B4 S3B5   
S4B1 S4B2 S4B3 S4B4 S4B5   
S5B1 S5B2 S5B3 S5B4 S5B5
```

Comment: what are you creating these matrices in?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to mention that. I'm using R.

Comment: You need to provide more details. Language, data structure, file type, etc...

Comment: Question needs more detail, hard to grasp exactly what you want.

Comment: Sorry, does it seem more clear now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [calculate the mean for each column of a matrix in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21807987/calculate-the-mean-for-each-column-of-a-matrix-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple. First, you should calculate `mean` for each column, then you should reshape resulting `1x25` vector into `5x5` matrix:

```
matrix(apply(data,2,mean), nrow=5, ncol=5, byrow=TRUE)
```

`apply(data,2,mean)` calculates mean values for each column of `data` and `matrix` constructs a `5x5` matrix from its results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `apply` function to calculate the mean for every column.

You can use it  this way :

```
apply(M, 2, mean) # where M is your data (presumably a matrix or a data frame)
```

And then put each result in an entry in your matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution here is to use the vectorized `colMeans` function (as `apply` being a `for` loop, is becoming inefficient as the data set grows). Try this

```
matrix(colMeans(M), ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE)
```