# Calculate sum, mean and variance for several columns of data in R

Tags: r, excel

I'm new to R. The professor asked us to obtain sum, mean and variance for several columns of data which are in Excel form. Now, I want to try to use R to solve them rather than enter the formula in Excel and drag. I have imported the data into R and they are correctly displayed. I can use the commands `sum ()` and `sd ()` and `var ()` for EACH column.

My question is: is there a way to let R display the sum, sd, and variance for each column at the same time? (Rather than calculating these again and again for each column).

I mean something like `colSum(col1, col2, col3,...)` and the line just shows the sum for each column.

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21807987/calculate-the-mean-for-each-column-of-a-matrix-in-r

Comment: `colSums` is there for the column sums, but you will have to use `lapply` with a custom function for the `sd` and `var` across columns..

Comment: @RichScriven Thanks! Check my answer. It worked in rstudio.

Answer (score 10):

More generally you would do something like:

```
sapply(data, sum)
sapply(data, var)
sapply(data, sd)
```

Or in one line as suggested by Agile Bean:

```
sapply(data, function(x) c(sum=sum(x), var=var(x), sd=sd(x)))
```

Comment: this is a nice solution - just to avoid redundancy, you can express the above three lines by `funs <- function(x) { c(sum=sum(x), var=var(x), sd=sd(x))}   sapply(data, funs)` For more than three functions, this would still remain two lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

I just figured it out. Basically I need to use colSums() and colMeans().
For example, colSums (,data[2:5]). This means we can calculate the sum for each column from column 2 to column 5.

Comment: for large datasets, this might run faster: `data[2:5] %>% map_dbl(sum)`