# How to calculate mean value of all columns of datarame

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I have a data frame and I want to calculate the mean of all columns and save it into a new dataframe. I found this solution [calculate the mean for each column of a matrix in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21807987/calculate-the-mean-for-each-column-of-a-matrix-in-r) however, this is only for matrix and not dataframe

```
structure(list(TotFlArea = c(1232, 596, 708, 1052, 716), logg_weighted_assess = c(13.7765298160156, 
13.1822275291412, 13.328376420438, 13.3076293132057, 13.5164823091252
), TypeDwel1.2.Duplex = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TypeDwelApartment.Condo = c(0, 
1, 1, 1, 1), TypeDwelTownhouse = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0), Age_new.70 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), Age_new0.1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Age_new16.40 = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 0), Age_new2.5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Age_new41.70 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), Age_new6.15 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1), LandFreehold = c(1, 
1, 1, 0, 1), LandLeasehold.prepaid = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0), LandOthers = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), cluster_K_mean.1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "data.frame")
```

Can you please advise how I can do this?

**Note: my data frame can have NA values which should be excluded from mean calculation**

Comment: You can use `colMeans` which work for data.frame/matrix i.e. `colMeans(yourdata, na.rm = TRUE)` (assuming all columns are numeric)

Comment: `colMeans(yourdata, na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

As @akrun pointed out. Also another alternative

```
apply(df, 2, mean)
```

where `2` means by column and `1` is by row.

However, besides its flexibility (e.g. changing from mean to mode or applying to selected columns only `apply(df[,c('a', 'b')], 2, mean)`) below shows the disadvantage to using `apply` (in terms of speed)

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

# dummy data
x <- 1e7
df <- data.table(a = 1:x )
y <- letters[2:10]
df[, (y) := lapply(2:10, \(i) a+i)]

# benchmark
z <- 
microbenchmark(colMeans = {colMeans(df)}
               , apply = {apply(df, 2, mean)}
               , times = 30
               )

plot(z)
```

[image: benchmark]

Comment: If you're going to provide an alternative, you should add some commentary about when to prefer one over the other.

Comment: Thanks, @GregorThomas.
1 pro of using `apply` would be the flexibility in case of the change in function needed. On the other hand, I do acknowledge its lower speed vs `colMeans`

Comment: Great - much better answer with a little commentary.